# Creating dispersion plots from a data frame

Tags: r

I have the data frame `mydata_x`:

```
   sex age height_seca1 height_chad1 height_DL weight_alog1
1    F  19         1800         1797       180           70
2    F  19         1682         1670       167           69
3    F  21         1765         1765       178           80
4    F  21         1829         1833       181           74
5    F  21         1706         1705       170          103
6    F  18         1607         1606       160           76
7    F  19         1578         1576       156           50
8    F  19         1577         1575       156           61
9    F  21         1666         1665       166           52
10   F  17         1710         1716       172           65
11   F  28         1616         1619       161           66
12   F  22         1648         1644       165           58
13   F  19         1569         1570       155           55
14   F  19         1779         1777       177           55
15   M  18         1773         1772       179           70
16   M  18         1816         1809       181           81
17   M  19         1766         1765       178           77
18   M  19         1745         1741       174           76
19   M  18         1716         1714       170           71
20   M  21         1785         1783       179           64
21   M  19         1850         1854       185           71
22   M  31         1875         1880       188           95
23   M  26         1877         1877       186          106
24   M  19         1836         1837       185          100
25   M  18         1825         1823       182           85
26   M  19         1755         1754       174           79
27   M  26         1658         1658       165           69
28   M  20         1816         1818       183           84
29   M  18         1755         1755       175           67
```

My aim is to create separate histograms, boxplots and density distributions for each column of `mydata_x` containing continuous data (i.e excepting the `age` column) and save these plots as `.jpeg` files to the working directory using the file naming structure: `hist_mydata_x_age`, `boxplot_mydata_x_height_seca1`, `density_mydata_x_height_chad1`. Also ensuring appropriately labelled headers for the plots. I am required not to use any 'extra' R packages. 
Any help would be greatly thanked as I have attempted numerous approaches with limited success.

Comment: Please post what you have tried so far and where you're having issues.

Comment: I'm trying to string together the hist function using the following code: pts = list(x = hist[,mydata_2$age], y = hist[,mydata_2$height_seca1])
Error in hist[, mydata_2$age] : 
  object of type 'closure' is not subsettable

Comment: I'm trying to get more than one histogram plot other than computing one at a time. In a sense, stringing functions together. Would the function do.call be uselful? I've tried the following code: pts = do.call(, list(x = hist$age, y = hist$height_seca1)) but I get the same error.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like this?

```
sapply(names(mydata_x)[-1], function(name){
  # Histogram
  h.name <- paste0("hist_mydata_x_", name)
  png(paste0(h.name,".jpg"))
  hist(mydata_x[,name], main=h.name, xlab=name)
  dev.off()
  # Boxplot
  b.name <- paste0("boxplot_mydata_x_", name)
  png(paste0(b.name, ".jpg"))
  boxplot(mydata_x[,name], main=b.name, xlab=name)
  dev.off()
  # Density
  d.name <- paste0("density_mydata_x_", name)
  png(paste0(d.name, ".jpg"))
  plot(density(mydata_x[,name]), main=d.name)
  dev.off()
})
```

Here `mydata_x` is data.frame with data from your original question. `sapply(names(mydata_x)[-1], function(name){...})` executes function for all columns of `mydata_x` except `sex` (as far as it holds factors).

Function for each column generates proper names for histogram, boxplot and density plot and plots them to `png()` device, thus they are stored in current working directory.

Function generates 15 plots (5 columns x 3 types). For example, `hist_mydata_x_height_chad1.jpg`:

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure how to go about implementing that code. Could you break it down a bit more. Possibly display the plots in R?